# Не могу подключить экран к ардуино, чтобы на нем отображалась скорость

Tags: arduino

Написал код, чтобы ардуино регулировал скорость:

```
#include <Servo.h>


Servo servol;

void setup() {

servo.attach (5); }

void loop() {

int potent = analogRead(5);

potent = map(potent, 0, 1024, 0, 180);

servol.write (potent);

delay(2); }
```

Как теперь вывести эту скорость на экран?

Comment: Вывести на какой экран?

Comment: На экран компьютера или на светодиодный экранчик для Arduino 128*64, монохромный такой.

Вот типо такого:
https://a.aliexpress.com/_DFqAtDN

Мне хоть куда-нибудь уже вывести.. Ох..

Comment: От того куда хотите вывести очень сильно зависит код. Если на экран компьютера - отправляйте в Serial, на компе смотрите через Serial Monitor в Arduino IDE. Если на ЖК экран - зависит от конкретного экрана его интерфейса его подключения. Для текстового и графического экранов будет разный код. Для 128x64 теоретически вот эта статья вам может помочь http://wiki.amperka.ru/products:display-lcd-graphic-128x64

Comment: На экран компа - пишите программу, которая читает COM-порт и выводит на экран. Для вывода на ЖКИ - надо либу подключить, в зависимости от используемого дисплея  и через неё выводить

Comment: Ещё задержка у Вас маленькая больно - хотя-бы 100 млСек

Comment: Скорость чего? Не вижу скорости в коде. Вижу что ручка и серва на одном пине.